# Firefox "Script error" in resource://gre/components/nsLoginManager.js

Tags: javascript, firefox, passwords, exploit

Since yesterday I added a little function to one of my sites, to send me all the Javascript errors, that the clients get. It looks like this.

```
window.onerror = errorHandler;
function errorHandler(message, file, line) {
// send to server
}
```

For one of my users I am getting this:

```
message: Script Error.
file: resource://gre/components/nsLoginManager.js
line: 0
```

The user agent is `Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 5.1; rv:23.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/23.0`.
The error happens on every page that is loaded, but only for one user, although many others should be using the current Firefox.
I also tried it myself in Firefox 23 and did not get the error.

As far as I found out yet, the nsLoginManager is the firefox reponsible for the loading and storing of passwords in firefox. So two possibilities came to my mind:

1. The user has a thirdparty password manager installed
2. An exploit might have taken over the users password manager

Does anyone have other or more detailed ideas on this?

Comment: Since nobody else is getting the error, I think it's more likely that his installation is somehow corrupt...

Comment: It's probably a problem with a firefox plugin of the user.